# master reset - clear listview and data from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I have got a listview filled with contacts and a XML file where the contacts are stored.

I would like to create a button which would act as a kind of Master Reset button. Basically, when the button is pressed the program (data) should reset and act like it was turned on for the first time - no contacts should be there. So, the listview should be cleared and data should be removed from the XML file.

This is how my XML file (Contacts.xml) looks like:

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Hometown>Washington</Hometown>
    <Address>231 Main Street</Address>
    <Birthday>130299511993682082</Birthday>
    <Phone>555-555-555</Phone>
    <Email>john@gmail.com</Email>
    <AdditionalInfo>Skype: john.123</AdditionalInfo>
  </Person>
</People>
```

... and here is the listview (listView1):

[image: Listview]

I know how to clear the listview but I have no idea how to "reset" the XML file.

Any ideas?

@EDIT:

Here is what I have tried, based on your suggestions:

```
    void MasterReset()
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string phonebook_path = path + "\\Phonebook\\Contacts.xml";
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(phonebook_path);
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People");
        xNode.InnerXml = "";
        xDoc.Save(phonebook_path);
        listView1.Clear();
    }
```

But it does not work, when I load the app again - the contacts are still there.

Comment: Why don't you just keep 1 master file, which contains no 'data' (only the raw XML). Then, load it (XDocument.Load) and keep it in memory and save it to a new file, thus keeping the original untouched.

Comment: I am really trying hard to understand what did you mean, but have no success doing so. Why would I keep the original file if I want settings to reset? In that way, I would have multiple XML files. Whenever user presses the Master Reset button, it would create a new XML file? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Have a variable which stores your initial load and save it to a file or keep it in memory

Comment: I have uploaded the code here, please take a look at it: http://www.sendspace.com/file/p0d27d

Comment: It is denied where I am (work restriction). How many XML files do you have? Is it one with multiple entries for multiple contacts, or 1 file per contact?

Comment: My original comment should have read: Why don't you just keep 1 master file, which contains no 'data' (only the raw XML). Then, load it (XDocument.Load) and keep it in memory and save `any new contacts as a new file`, thus keeping the original untouched.

Comment: No, I have got only one XML file (Contacts.xml) where ALL the contacts are stored. This is an example with the listview containing only one contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the data in the xml file, you first need to create an `XmlDocument` object

```
using System.Xml;  //Don't forget this

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/Contacts.xml");
```

Next, you need to select the "people" node and set the InnerXml to nothing, effectively clearing the node.

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("People");
node.InnerXml = "";
```

And finally, you will want to save the changes to the file.

```
doc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/Contacts.xml");
```

if you want to learn more about how to interact with xml, take a look at these: 
[msdn article on the XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[msdn article on the Sytem.Xml Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Check the xml file and make sure it really has not been edited. Also, try using just one slash between items in your path, not sure why there's two...

Comment: OK, I see why you used the double backslash. Single backslashes give this error about escape sequences or something. Instead, use single forward slashes, they work for paths as well. Backslashes **could** be the problem

Comment: Actually yes, it is edited, I checked now. But the problem is contacts are still there, I thought I was going to remove them this way. @EDIT: Are you saying that backslashes are the problem!?

Comment: Does your program re-read the xml file every time it starts up?

Comment: Please take a look at this, I have uploaded part of the code which I think you are asking me about: http://www.sendspace.com/file/qf4m0i

Comment: At the end of the program, in `Main_FormClosing`, you seem to write all of your contacts back to the xml file in a foreach statement after you've cleared the "People" node. Comment out the foreach and it should work.

Comment: Just that single line? But hey, will the program still work? I mean, will it work properly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42081/discussion-between-blue0500-and-exinta-enea)